# Implements a custom template for Langage switcher

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I've tried to implement a custom template in `MY_THEME/templates/general/links--locale-block.tpl.php`. But it isn't called even if the block is correctly configured and placed in the right region.

I've never done any templating before, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: this may help you https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: How you created your block? Using views or Block UI or in custom module?

Comment: I guess the block is already installed with the I18n module. It is implemented in `locale.module` which is a core module. (Language switcher)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer is also helpful finding the template name. maybe you could also just preprocess the $variables and add some classes or something. sometimes only css can help you too ;)

Comment: @IsmaH Remember always to clear drupal cache after creating any template for block or view or page.